# Warning: non-variable type argument in type pattern is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

Tags: scala

I'm using Scala 2.10.6 due to corporate restrictions. How can I get rid of the warning:

```
warning: non-variable type argument Market in type pattern () => Market is unchecked 
         since it is eliminated by erasure
```

in the following definition:

```
case (payoff: Payoff, mktFun: (() => Market)) => {
    val mkt = mktFun()
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, for instance, make a dedicated datatype `case class Foo(p: PayOff, f: () => Market)` which you can use as a pattern, instead of a generic tuple.

```
case Foo(payoff, mktFun) => {
    val mkt = mktFun()
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution that works is defining a custom function type:

```
type MktFun = () => Market
```

and then:

```
case (payoff: Payoff, mktFun: MktFun) => {
    val mkt = mktFun()
    // ...
}
```

and I don't get the warning anymore.

Comment: Do mind that this relies on a bug that got fixed in 2.11.x. So if you ever upgrade the warning will be back. And after all the problem that is warned for is still there.